# Open and closed sets for j-Spec $A$.

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

The following is from Matsumura,

> **Theorem 4.10** Let $A$ be a ring and $M$ a finite $A$-module.
>
> (i) For any non-negative integer $r$ set $$U_r = \{p \in \text{Spec} \space A | M_\mathfrak{p} \text{can be generated over} A_\mathfrak{p} \text{by} \space r \space \text{elements}\}$$ 
>   then $U_r$ is an open subset of Spec $A$.
>
> (ii) If $M$ is a module of finite presentation then the set $$U_F = \{\mathfrak{p} \in \text{Spec} \space A | M_\mathfrak{p} \text{is a free} \space A_\mathfrak{p}-\text{module}\}$$ is open in Spec $A$.

However, on page $37$, he states

> For $n= 1, 2, ...$, the subset $X_n = \{ \mathfrak{p} \in$ j-Spec $A | \mu(\mathfrak{p}, M) \geq n\}$ is closed in $j$-Spec $A$ by Theorem $4.10$.

where $\mu(\mathfrak{p},M)$ is the cardinality of a minimal generating set of $M_\mathfrak{p}$ over $A_\mathfrak{p}$, and j-Spec $A$ is the set of all prime ideals which can be written as the intersection of maximal ideals.

By the subspace topology, (for j-Spec $A$) we have that

$U_n = \{p \in$ j-Spec $A | M_\mathfrak{p} \text{can be generated over} A_\mathfrak{p} \text{by} \space n \space \text{elements}\}$ is open in j-Spec $A$.

But

$U_n = \{p \in$ j-Spec $A | M_\mathfrak{p} \text{can be generated over} A_\mathfrak{p} \text{by} \space n \space \text{elements}\}$

$= \{ \mathfrak{p} \in$ j-Spec $A | \mu(\mathfrak{p}, M) \leq n\}$

So we can obviously see that the complement of this, which is

$\{ \mathfrak{p} \in$ j-Spec $A | \mu(\mathfrak{p}, M) > n\}$

must be closed in j-Spec $A$. However, Matsumura says that

$\{ \mathfrak{p} \in$ j-Spec $A | \mu(\mathfrak{p}, M) \geq n\}$

must be closed...which I don't understand, because the inequality is not strict (so it is not the complement of an open set). Is it possible if anybody can explain this to me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U_{r-1} = \{p \in \text{Spec} \space A | M_\mathfrak{p} \text{ can be generated over} A_\mathfrak{p} \text{by} \space r-1 \space \text{elements}\}$ is also an open set in Spec $A$. Thus $U_{n-1} \cap j$-Spec $A$ is open in $j$-Spec $A$. And $X_n$ is just the complement of $U_{n-1} \cap j$-Spec $A$, hence closed.